# Is it possible to connect localhost applications in webscarab?

Tags: php, webscarab

When I try to connect the locally hosted application like: localhost/myapplications.php to webscarab means apache tomcat reports an alert message as 404 not found.

But on giving the live "URL" as http://www.myapps.com gets synchronised with the webscarab.

Is it possible to connect the local appliations with the webscarab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using http://localhost/myapplications.php ?

BTW you might like to try OWASP ZAP instead of WebScarab, which is being actively maintained ;)

Comment: Hi Instead of using the "WebScarab" ur asking me to try "OWASP ZAP"  ?

Comment: That my suggestion - WebScarab is not really being actively developed, whereas ZAP is the most actively developed open source web security tool. But I'm the ZAP project lead, so I'm biased ;)